# How to render the list in react-native-sortable-list?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

How to re-render the data? I update the data but it is not output.

[Sample code](https://github.com/StekolschikovV/pomdo/blob/master/src/screens/task/index.js#L34) on the line 34.

```
setInterval(() => {
    let d= this.state.data;
    d.push({
        image: 'https://placekitten.com/200/240',
        text: 'Chloe3',
    })
    this.setState({
        data: d
    })
}, 1500)
```

I'm using the plugin: [pinreact-native-sortable-list](https://github.com/gitim/react-native-sortable-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly updating your state variable. You are mutating the state by inserting a new element into the `data` array. This change is not triggering any state update, hence `render` method is not called. As per `React` [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), we should not mute the state directly

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Change the state update as (using **ES6**)

```
setInterval(() => {
  let d= this.state.data;
  const newRecord = {
    image: 'https://placekitten.com/200/240',
    text: 'Chloe3',
  };
  this.setState({
    data: [ ...d, newRecord]
  })
}, 1500);
```

Or using [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.concat([newRecord])
});
```

Hope this will help!